# Rails not serving assets in development mode

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, asset-pipeline

Well it's the first time I set up a Rails app from the beginning and I just created my first view.

When I run the server I get a 404 Not Found error when trying to load the `application.js` file.

**Layout**

```
<html>
  <head>
    <%= yield :head %>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>If you're not and Admin you shouldn't be here!</h1>
    <%= yield %>

    <%= javascript_include_tag 'application' %>
    <% yield :script %>
    <script>

      $(function(){
        alert('Hey')
      })
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

**application.js**

```
//= require jquery
```

**environment/development.rb**

...

```
config.assets.debug = false
config.assets.compile = false
config.assets.digest = true
```

...

And when I run on terminal `rake assets:precompile` I get this error:

> rake aborted!
>
> Don't know how to build task 'assets:precompile'

What is causing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After running `rake assets:precompile --tasks` the precompile task was not listed.

I found out that a require on `config/application.rb` was missing:

```
require 'rails/all'
```

After adding this the app started precompiling and serving assets (actually there were minor errors with the gems I tried to install, I just had to remove the configuration files and then everything worked fine)

Comment: Why was rails not required? What kind of tutorial were you following?

Answer (score 2):

To resolve this, add the following to `config/application.rb`:

```
require 'sprockets/railtie'
```

For more information see [here.](https://github.com/rails/sprockets-rails)

Answer (score 0):

Try to set `config.assets.compile = true` and try again. It should work after that.

Cheers!

Comment: no, it didn't work. i couldn't run the precompile and couldn't load the JS file